# How to prove that there is a $z\in(0,y)$ such that $f(z)=a$ for every $a>0$ given the inequality below

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous such that i) $f(0)=0$ , and ii) for every $x\geq{0}$ there exists some $y\geq{0}$ such that $f(y)>3f(x)$. Show that for every $a>0$ there exists $z>0$ such that $f(z)=a$

Here is what I did:
For $x=0: f(y)>3f(0)\implies f(y)>0$

f is continuous in $[0,y]$ , $f(0)\neq{f(y)}$ Therefore from the Intermediate Value Theorem for every $a\in(f(0),f(y))\;\exists\;z\in(0,y)$ such that $f(z)=a$.
I want to use the induction method in some way to expand the interval $(0,y)$ to $(0,\infty)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is bounded, i.e. there exists some $M > 0$ such that $f(x) \leq M$ for all $x>0$. We can then argue that there will be some $y>0$ such that $f(y) \ge 3M$, contradicting the initial assumption. This means that $f$ is unbounded and the result follows from the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: How do you know f is differentiable to apply the Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: @WolfX491 I meant intermediate value...

Comment: Oh thats perfect then!

Answer (score 1):

Take $y\in(0,\infty)$ such that $f(y)>3f(0)=0$. I will prove that, for each $n\in\Bbb Z_+$, there is some $y_n\in(0,\infty)$ such that $f(y_n)\geqslant3^nf(y)$. If $n=0$, you can just take $y_0=y$. Now, let $n\in\Bbb Z_+$ and suppose that there is some $y_n\in(0,\infty)$ such that $f(y_n)\geqslant3^nf(y)$. Take $y_{n+1}\in(0,\infty)$ such that $f(y_{n+1})>3f(y_n)$. Then $f(y_{n+1})>3\times3^nf(y)=3^{n+1}f(y)$. In particular, $f(y_{n+1})\geqslant3^{n+1}f(y)$.

Now, if $a\in(0,\infty)$, then, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}3^nf(y)=\infty$, there is some $n\in\Bbb Z_+$ such that $3^nf(y)>a$. But then $f(y_n)>a$, and therefore it follows from the Intermediate Value Theorem that $a=f(z)$ for some $z\in[0,y_n]$.

Comment: Elegant proof, thanks!